# MLE of uniform $(\theta,\theta^2)$

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, maximum-likelihood

Let $X_1...X_n$ be from uniform ($\theta,\theta^2)$ where $\theta>1$ I seek the MLE. I've seen similar problems, but I think this one might be more interesting. Intuitively, we think $X_{(1)}$ should estimate theta. However I think since $\theta >1$ there is no MLE as this function blows up close to one. Is this correct?

Edit: bad picture explaining my reasoning: 
[image]

Comment: Please also note that the last remark in my answer is not the thing that you had to think about in advance. You should automatically get this inequality since the likelihood function differs from zero iff **both** inequalities $\theta\leq X_{(1)}$ and $X_{(n)}\leq \theta^2$ holds. And on your chart a disjunction is drawn, not a conjunction of regions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Write likelihood function: 
$$ 
L(\theta, X_1,\ldots,X_n) = \frac{1}{(\theta^2-\theta)^n}\cdot \mathbb 1_{\{X_{(1)}\geq \theta, X_{(n)}\leq \theta^2\}} = \frac{1}{(\theta^2-\theta)^n}\cdot \mathbb 1_{\left\{\sqrt{X_{(n)}}\leq\theta\leq X_{(1)}\right\}} 
$$
So in your picture you should have a function that decreases on the interval $[\sqrt{X_{(n)}}, X_{(1)}]$ and is zero on the other parts of $[1,\infty)$. And the MLE is the left point : $\hat\theta=\sqrt{X_{(n)}}$ not the right since the function decreases inside interval.

Note also that $\sqrt{X_{(n)}}\leq X_{(1)}$ since $X_{(n)}\leq \theta^2$ and then $\sqrt{X_{(n)}}\leq \theta$, and $X_{(1)}\geq \theta$. So at your picture points on the axis should be swapped.